# 3D object takes long time to show in RealityKit

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I am working on RealityKit app project and I have a question.
when viewing a 3d model it takes more than one minute to show up, the app loads the models from firebase fast but it takes time to show on the screen and I am using iPad 7 generation to run the app.
I tried obj and usdz format and there is no difference

This is the code I use

```
func View3DObject( Name : String){
        
        //start of bring models from firebase
        @ObservedObject var model = Model(name: Name, category: .animals)
        
        //set object on floor
        let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(plane: .any, classification: .floor)
           
        
        //get object from database
           let resultModel = model.asyncLoadModelEntity(){ result in
            
               
        //enable intraction and movment
            result.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
               self.arView.installGestures([.translation, .rotation, .scale],for: result)
   
            
            anchorEntity.addChild(result)
               
      

        }
        
        
        //add object to secne
            self.arView.scene.anchors.append(anchorEntity)
            print("Model is added to the scene" )


    }
    
}
```

asyncLoadModelEntity function:

```
 func asyncLoadModelEntity(completion: @escaping (_ result: ModelEntity) -> Void) -> ModelEntity{
        var result = ModelEntity()
        FirebaseStorageHelper.asyncDownloadFilesystem(relativePath: "models/\(self.name).obj") { localUrl in
            self.cancellable = ModelEntity.loadModelAsync(contentsOf: localUrl)
                .sink(receiveCompletion: { loadCompletion in
               
                    switch loadCompletion{
                    case .failure(let error): print("Unable to load modelEntity for \(self.name). Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                case .finished:
                    break
                }
            }, receiveValue:{ modelEntity in
                result = modelEntity
                self.modelEntity = modelEntity

                // self.modelEntity?.scale *= self.scaleCompensation
                print("modelEntity for \(self.name) has been loaded")
                completion(result)
            })
        }
        return result
    }
```

And this is the console

```
022-03-06 01:43:27.800057+0300 MarsamApp[689:48039] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
2022-03-06 01:43:27.801598+0300 MarsamApp[689:48039] Metal API Validation Enabled
2022-03-06 01:43:28.325928+0300 MarsamApp[689:48039] [AssetTypes] Registering library (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreRE.framework/default.metallib) that already exists in shader manager. Library will be overwritten.
2022-03-06 01:43:28.413704+0300 MarsamApp[689:48242] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000008] The project's Bundle ID is inconsistent with either the Bundle ID in 'GoogleService-Info.plist', or the Bundle ID in the options if you are using a customized options. To ensure that everything can be configured correctly, you may need to make the Bundle IDs consistent. To continue with this plist file, you may change your app's bundle identifier to 'com.MarsamApp'. Or you can download a new configuration file that matches your bundle identifier from https://console.firebase.google.com/ and replace the current one.
2022-03-06 01:43:28.455746+0300 MarsamApp[689:48246] [general] *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver validateAllowedClass:forKey:] allowed unarchiving safe plist type ''NSString' (0x1f345e358) [/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework]' for key 'NS.keys', even though it was not explicitly included in the client allowed classes set: '{(
    "'NSDate' (0x1f34536c0) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]",
    "'NSDictionary' (0x1f3453828) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]"
)}'. This will be disallowed in the future.
2022-03-06 01:43:28.477648+0300 MarsamApp[689:48246] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60900000 started
2022-03-06 01:43:28.478318+0300 MarsamApp[689:48246] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see)
2022-03-06 01:43:28.491851+0300 MarsamApp[689:48246] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2022-03-06 01:43:28.498980+0300 MarsamApp[689:48242] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
2022-03-06 01:43:28.499730+0300 MarsamApp[689:48242] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023220] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:FIREventScreenView parameters:] to log a screen view event. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
2022-03-06 01:43:28.634100+0300 MarsamApp[689:48039] [Assets] Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/suFeatheringCreateMergedOcclusionMask.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
2022-03-06 01:43:28.718313+0300 MarsamApp[689:48039] [Assets] Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arKitPassthrough.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
2022-03-06 01:43:28.720479+0300 MarsamApp[689:48039] [Assets] Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/drPostAndComposition.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
2022-03-06 01:43:28.722138+0300 MarsamApp[689:48039] [Assets] Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arSegmentationComposite.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
2022-03-06 01:43:28.724000+0300 MarsamApp[689:48039] [Assets] Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute0.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
2022-03-06 01:43:28.726142+0300 MarsamApp[689:48039] [Assets] Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute1.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
2022-03-06 01:43:28.727083+0300 MarsamApp[689:48039] [Assets] Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute2.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
2022-03-06 01:43:28.741687+0300 MarsamApp[689:48039] [Assets] Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute3.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
2022-03-06 01:43:28.742755+0300 MarsamApp[689:48039] [Assets] Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute4.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
2022-03-06 01:43:28.743783+0300 MarsamApp[689:48039] [Assets] Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute5.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
2022-03-06 01:43:28.744806+0300 MarsamApp[689:48039] [Assets] Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute6.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
2022-03-06 01:43:28.745873+0300 MarsamApp[689:48039] [Assets] Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute7.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
2022-03-06 01:43:28.747365+0300 MarsamApp[689:48039] [Foundation.Serialization] Json Parse Error line 18: Json Deserialization; unknown member 'EnableARProbes' - skipping.
2022-03-06 01:43:28.747443+0300 MarsamApp[689:48039] [Foundation.Serialization] Json Parse Error line 20: Json Deserialization; unknown member 'EnableGuidedFilterOcclusion' - skipping.
2022-03-06 01:43:29.018288+0300 MarsamApp[689:48039] throwing -10878
2022-03-06 01:43:29.020976+0300 MarsamApp[689:48039] throwing -10878
2022-03-06 01:43:29.021108+0300 MarsamApp[689:48039] throwing -10878
2022-03-06 01:43:29.021210+0300 MarsamApp[689:48039] throwing -10878
2022-03-06 01:43:29.021303+0300 MarsamApp[689:48039] throwing -10878
2022-03-06 01:43:29.021756+0300 MarsamApp[689:48039] throwing -10878
2022-03-06 01:43:29.021864+0300 MarsamApp[689:48039] throwing -10878
2022-03-06 01:43:29.021971+0300 MarsamApp[689:48039] throwing -10878
2022-03-06 01:43:29.022073+0300 MarsamApp[689:48039] throwing -10878
2022-03-06 01:43:29.222669+0300 MarsamApp[689:48250] [general] *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver validateAllowedClass:forKey:] allowed unarchiving safe plist type ''NSString' (0x1f345e358) [/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework]' for key 'NS.keys', even though it was not explicitly included in the client allowed classes set: '{(
    "'NSDate' (0x1f34536c0) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]",
    "'NSDictionary' (0x1f3453828) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]"
)}'. This will be disallowed in the future.

Model is added to the scene
Warning (secondary thread): in AppendProperty at line 859 of sdf/path.cpp -- Can only append a property 'preliminary:anchoring:type' to a prim path (/)
Warning (secondary thread): in AppendProperty at line 859 of sdf/path.cpp -- Can only append a property 'triggers' to a prim path (/)
Warning (secondary thread): in AppendProperty at line 859 of sdf/path.cpp -- Can only append a property 'preliminary:anchoring:type' to a prim path (/)
modelEntity for Banana has been loaded
```

also, these are some sceneshots for the statistics
[sheep object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2JqT.jpg)
[frog object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hN7dX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

For fast loading and rendering, use AR models with a max polygon count of [100K](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/adding_visual_effects_in_ar_quick_look_and_realitykit) (models with 20K to 50K polygons are considerably "faster"), and textures of max 2K rez (however, 1K textures are better). A large amount of PBR materials also prevents fast loading.

Comment: Thank you andy, do you know a way that I can edit the objects I already have to satisfy the constraints you mentioned?

Comment: The only way to get an AR model satisfying to certain parameters is to create it in 3D authoring app from scratch. Very often models from TurboSquid are not suitable for AR apps because they are hi-rez.

Comment: Thank you so much, your comments are highly appreciated.